# Rolling a die $n$ times

Tags: probability

In a game of repeated die rolls, a player is allowed to roll a standard die up to $n$​ times, where $​n$​ is determined prior to the start of the game. On any roll except the last, the player may choose to either keep that roll as their final score, or continue rolling in hopes of a higher roll later on. If the player rolls all ​$n$ times, then after the ​$n^{\text{th}}$​ roll, the player must keep that roll as their final score. A player always acts to maximize their expected final score. Finally, let $v_n$​ denote the final score in a game with a max of ​$n$​ rolls allowed.

What I was thinking is using a Bernoulli Trial because we are rolling a die $n$ times. Using the Bernoulli Trail formula we get $$v_n = \binom{n}{1} \cdot\left(\frac{1}{6}\right) \cdot\left(1-\frac{1}{6}\right)^{n-1}.$$

How do I incorporate the fact that $n$ is determined prior to the game?What do I need to think about here?

Comment: Not sure what that expression has to do with anything.  As a suggestion:  work it pout for $n=2$.  What strategy do you use to decide whether or not to keep the first toss?  Once you have that, try $n=3$.

Comment: To use Bernoulli you have to decide what counts as a success and it must have a constant probability over the fixed number n of trials.

Comment: When you say "solve $v_n$" I am guessing you mean find the probability mass function?  Or do you mean a winning strategy that maximizes $v_n$?  What is the goal?

Comment: Winning strategy that maximizes $v_n$. Bad phrasing on my part. I removed it from the question so it may be more clear.

Comment: @lulu, So what I came up with is if the first roll is not a $6$, then roll it again and then you'll keep that final score. Probability would be something like $\frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{6}^2$?

Comment: What makes you think that strategy is optimal for $n=2$? Note:   Even if you follow that strategy, that computation makes no sense.  What probability are you trying to compute there?

Comment: Perhaps you should start slower.  What is the answer for $n=1$?

Comment: I take it $v_n$ is the _expected_ or _average_ final score. There's no single numeric final score.

Comment: $6$, you would want that to be your number because this is highest we could get, right?

Comment: Was the question asking you what score you wanted?  That seems like a silly question, doesn't it?

Comment: @aschepler, yes this is the expected final score.

Comment: @lulu, the expected value for one die would be $3.5$, so if you got a $3$ you would want to roll again?

Comment: There you go.  For $n=2$, the optimal strategy is to keep scores $≥4$ and roll again on $≤3$.  Given that, what is the expected value for $n=2$?

Comment: The idea ihere is to work recursively. Once you know $E_n$, figure out what $E_{n+1}$ o in terms of it.  Keep in mind that the optimal strategy will change as $n$ changes.  If $n=10^6$ say, you should clearly only keep a $6$..after all, you are sure to roll a $6$ eventually.  But this is not the case small $n$.

Comment: The expected value for $n=2$ would be $7$, but okay! That is interesting.

Comment: How could the answer possibly be $7$?  The maximum possible score is $6$.

Comment: Expected value for one die is $3.5$, so for two die it would be $7$?

Comment: Please review the rules of the game.  Then try again.